# Representation vector expansion in subgroup representation vectors

Tags: representation-theory

Imagine I have a Group $G$ and a representation of it acting on a vector space $V_G$.

Imagine that I have a subgroup of $G$ named $H$ and a representation of $H$ acting on $V_H$.

Consider a vector of $V_G$. Can I always expand it in terms of vectors in $V_H$?

EDIT::I am gonna give more info

the group $G$ is the isometry group of a (group) manifold $K$. This manifold is $K=G/H$; and $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$.

the vectors of $V_G$ are denoted as $|G_a>$; the vectors of $V_H$are denoted as $|h_i>$

The expansion I am looking forward to is

$|G_a>=\sum_i|h_i><h_i|G_a>$

It isn't specified how this inner product is supposed to be taken.

I am confused because, since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, wouldn't the vectors $|h_i>$ and $|G_a>$ be of the same vector space and thus, why make any difference?

Comment: What would that mean? What's the relationship between $V_G$ and $V_H$?

Comment: Is $V_{H}$ the restriction of $V_{G}$ to $H$? Also, what is $G_{H}$?

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh honestly I do not know. I am reading a physics review and it is far less precise than I would like. Would there be a difference if $V_H$ were the restriction of $V_G$ and if not?

Comment: Well, you do need to define $V_{H}$ somehow. The only obvious definition that is somewhat related to $V_{G}$ is the restriction to $H$. But it would be best if you figure out exactly what $V_{H}$ is and edit your question to include the definition.You say you want to expand a vector in $V_{G}$ in terms of vectors in $V_{H}$. First, this requires some relationship between these vector spaces and second, you need to define what you mean by expansion. As stated, it is not clear what you want to show.

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh I don't know if it will be helpful but I have edited the question providing more info